# Is there any official or unofficial support for Hologram Remoting using the Hololens 1 with Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm working on an application, and unfortunately all I have to use to test it is a Hololens 1.  Is there any way to achieve holographic remoting in Unity, or am I limited to building and deploying each and every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HoloLens, we can use the legacy WSA Holographic Emulation to achieve holographic remoting. Please note, the legacy WSA Holographic Emulation is only supported in Unity 2019 LTS, and Unity 2020 does not support it. For how to use it, please refer to this doc: [Preview and debug your app using Holographic Remoting and Play mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/preview-and-debug-your-app?tabs=wsa)

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

It's a shame how quickly MS deprecated the features surrounding the HL1, but I'll just have to build and deploy - I can't downgrade my Unity install, unfortunately.